# What happens if I assign to an int pointer a float variable address and vice-versa?

Tags: c, pointers

I was wondering what would happen if I gave an `int` pointer a `float` variable address and vice-versa, so I tried it but couldn't exactly understand what's happening so if anyone can explain I would be grateful.

```
int n = 5;
float f = 1.21;
float *pf = &n;
int *pn = &f;

printf("%p  %p\n", pn, pf);
printf("%p  %p\n", &f, &n);
printf("%d   %f \n", *pn, *pf);
printf("%f   %d \n", n, f);
printf("%d  %f \n", n, f);
```

Output:

```
0xffffcba8  0xffffcbac
0xffffcba8  0xffffcbac
1067114824   0.000000
0.000000   0
5  1.210000
```

Comment: It's called **undefined behavior** - so no in general it can't be described. The only valid print statement is the last one.

Comment: Also first and second print statements should be ok. After all they're just addresses.

Comment: @CmedCmbadi Please re-accept the [answer from chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174143/12139179), not mine. His one is way better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chqrlie´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174143/12139179) is way better than mine. Please re-accept his answer.

---

You should not abuse pointers and objects - Even not for curiosity reasons. The results of the 1., 2. and the 5. `printf` command are correct, but the results of the 3. and 4. `printf` command are products of Undefined Behavior, thus noone can explain them.

For more information about Undefined Behavior:
[Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Answer (score 3):

There is a number of instances of undefined behavior in your code:

- `int n = 5;` : OK
- `float f = 1.21;` : OK
- `float *pf = &n;` initializes a pointer with the value of a pointer to a different type. The C Standard makes no guarantees as to what this does nor as to what happens when you dereference this pointer. With `-Wall -W`, you would definitely get a warning for this, which you could silence with a cast: `float *pf = (float *)&n;`, yet the result is the same, dereferencing the pointer has undefined behavior.
- `int *pn = &f;` same as above.
- `printf("%p  %p\n", pn, pf);` -> you should cast the pointers as `(void *)` because `%p` expects a `void *` as an argument. On some rare systems (old Cray systems IIRC), pointers to `int`, `float` and `void` may have different representations, causing this call to `printf` to behave in unexpected ways. Use this instead:

  ```
  printf("%p  %p\n", (void *)pn, (void *)pf);
  ```
- `printf("%p  %p\n", &f, &n);` -> same problem. Use this instead:

  ```
  printf("%p  %p\n", (void *)&f, (void *)&n);
  ```

  The output is correct and the same for both expressions because your system is regular, but the C Standard does not guarantee it.
- `printf("%d   %f \n", *pn, *pf);` this one is correct but dereferencing the pointer has undefined behavior.
- `printf("%f   %d \n", n, f);` passing value of types different from the expected types has undefined behavior. The output you get is incorrect.
- `printf("%d  %f \n", n, f);` this one is correct and the output is `5  1.210000` as expected.

Comment: @4386427 I´m a fair player. This answer is way better than mine. I´ll let the OP know. But this is no reason to downvote my answer.

Comment: @4386427 This is indeed the best answer. Nevertheless downvoting the accepted answer is a bit _harsh_.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Maybe "harsh" but not wrong. Consider that.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I am on your side. :) I was just trying to say that _downvoting your answer_ is harsh. ... because it is not wrong.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I´d misunderstood it, sorry. ;-)

Comment: Just in case anyone wonders, I agree and did not DV RobertS' answer :)

Comment: @chqrlie ;>) - =)